# Downloading xlsm is disabled for anonymous user: What function is responsible for this access control?

Tags: 7, files

We have a D7.8 site with Panopoly 7.x-1.81. No access control modules.

A standard filefield is used for uploads and functions perfectly for the usual set of mime types.

We recently extended the list of allowable extensions in the field definition to include .xlsm

Our xlsm files are code-signed and certified by a Microsoft-approved cert provider.

We can upload the xlsm files no problem, and logged-in users can see the download link.

**However, anonymous users do not see the download link.

We are not sure what function could be deciding to block display of this filetype.**

Can anyone suggest possible avenues for investigation?

Comment: Are you using the private file system? If so, the user will need access to the entity (probably a node) that the file is attached to, to download the file. Do anonymous users have access to this entity?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, we found an answer for this one.
We needed to add the proper MIME Type for xlsm:
'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12'
Hope that helps!